# Como puedo sacar un dato de json node

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente codigo

json:

```
"detail": [
        {
            "sum01": 10
        },
        {
            "sum01": 10
        },
        {
            "sum01": 10
        }
    ],
```

codigo:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < detail.length; i++) {
                console.log(detail[i])
        }
```

lo que mi imprime es esto `{ sum01: 10 }{ sum01: 10 }` y lo que yo quiero que haga es tener es la variable ejemplo {sum01}, sum01
lo que quiero hacer es imprimir lo que esta dentro de las comillas de mi json pero no logro hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendas que leas en la web de develop mozzilla que esta muy bien explicado.
Fijate si te sirve esto

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Lo podrias solucionar de la siguiente manera

```
var obj = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c' };
console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // console: ['0', '1', '2']
```